# How to attach data source to module (which data source will be used for auto-completion in given module)

Tags: intellij-idea

I have module with all persistence-related stuff like entities, queries, etc. These queries are validated using some datasource. There is somewhere dialog allowing you to configure which data source will be used for which module/package. I found out, that wrong data source is being used, and I need to change it.

This dialog is extremely hard to find, but I always am able to find it within 10 minutes, but this time no luck even with 30 minutes. To recap: I need to say: this module will use this data source for code-completion etc. Checked multiple stackoverflow pages, intellij idea documentation, cannot find any mention about it.

Can someone advice where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Languages & Frameworks | SQL Resolution Scopes | Languages & Frameworks | [**SQL Resolution Scopes**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-languages-sql-resolution-scopes.html) to map the particular Data Source to a particular file or a directory in project.